# Embjers store.createRecord or store.push not updating view

Tags: ember.js, view, ember-data, push

I'm trying to create a new record and push it into the store. I can persist it  just fine (and i'll push to the store after successfully persisting, once i figure this out), but the view/template isn't being refreshed. I know persistence works because, if I refresh the entire page, the new record appears.

I also tried this.store.push(), and nothing happens. I've looked around and everyone seems to be using filter() but only on a child set of records in a parent controller...

Thanks in advance, i have feeling its something really basic.

**route/projects**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.find('projects');
    }
});
```

**controllers/projects**

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions: {
        createProject: function() {
            var title = this.get('newProjectTitle');
            var description = this.get('newProjectDescription');
            if (!title.trim()) { return; }

            // Create the new Project model
            var project = this.store.createRecord('project', {
                title: title,
                description: description
            });

            project.save();    
            this.set('newProjectTitle', '');
            this.set('newProjectDescription', '');
        }
    }
});
```

**projects.hbs**

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="title" value=newProjectTitle}}
    {{input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="description" value=newProjectDescription action="createProject"}}
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" {{action 'createProject'}}>Create this Project</button>

    <ul class="list-group">
        {{#each project in model}}
            {{#link-to 'project' project}}
            <li class="list-group-item">
                {{project.id}} - {{project.title}}
            </li>
            {{/link-to}}
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up going with.. which works.. but is this the best way to do this?

```
var model = this.get('model');
model.pushObject(project);
```

I also found that...

```
var posts = this.store.find('post'); //network request.
var posts = this.store.all('post'); //no network request, but does live reload
```

[Ember.js Models:Finding Reords](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/models/finding-records/)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the Setup Controller method -

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model);
  }
```

Use above method in route/projects.js file. 
your code will be like -

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.find('projects');
    }
setupController: function(controller, model) {
        controller.set('model', model);
      }

});
```

you can also refer this link for more information -

http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/routing/setting-up-a-controller/

Comment: since i stuck to the naming convention, I don't need to add that. It's the default behavior for a controller.  'App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  // The code below is the default behavior, so if this is all you
  // need, you do not need to provide a setupController implementation
  // at all.
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model);
  }
});'

Comment: Can you check one thing. in your template file try to log the value of model like  - {{log model}} see if that contains new value or old one.

Comment: Yes you are correct about the setupController hook but in your case you are not changing the route so model hook will not get called by itself you will need to write some method to setup the controller's model. If you do like this controller.set('content',model); your view will get auto refreshed